# How to get frequency of all terms in an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have a corpus of documents indexed . I also stored the term vectors when indexing. Now I want to retrieve term vectors of all documents satisfying some filtering options. 
I was able to get term vector for a single document or for a set of documents by providing the document IDs. But is there a way to get term vectors for all the documents without providing document IDs?
Eventually what I want to do is to get the frequency counts of all the terms in a field, for all documents in an index (i.e., a bag of words matrix).

I am using elasticsearch-py as a client.

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Seems like you need to use an aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with the bag of words matrix? There are many out-of-the-box ways to embed sentences in elastic and perform vector/semantic search that skip over the BOW approach. See this blog here: https://www.elastic.co/search-labs/blog/articles/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch

If you specifically just want to calculate the matrix though, I think the best way is to do it with a python script either at index time or as an additional pipeline step later.
You can use the CountVectorized from scikit learn for example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Then you can still add the counts / each vector to your documents in the index.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
print(X.toarray())
```